# find angle in square which is added for variable angle of center

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, computer-science, coordinate-systems

There is a square with fix lenth(2a). $O$ is the center point of square. $OB$ is an other line which is make a beta angle with $OA$ line. Angle of $OA$ line is changed between $0$ degree to $360$ degree. $C$ is a point in $OA$. But always $OC$ and $BC$ orthogonal and $B$ is going on lines of square. As well as, always I have the value of length of $OC(l)$.
I have to find the beta $(AOB)$ angle for some programming step.
I have used this trigonometry equation to solve this problem. but some period of the theta angle, giving wrong answers.

$l / \cos (\beta) = a / \sin(\beta + \theta)$

.....
.....

$\tan \beta = { (a/l) / \cos \theta   -  \tan \theta }$

[image]

Comment: So if you're finding an angle, you must be using inverse trig functions? You should know that the domains of inverse trig functions are truncated (that means they do not range from 0 to 360). This could give you wrong answers in certain angle ranges (depending on which inverse trig function you are using).

Comment: Do you mean, i have to know about the domain of OB line. is it 0 to PI/2 or PI/2 to PI  like wise?

Comment: No, I don't mean that. I can't be more specific without knowing which inverse trig function you use to find your "final answer." Of you could Google "domain of [name of inverse trig function]" and discover it yourself.

Comment: according to my equation, just i have the value of tan beta. by **arctan** i can find the beta. beta should −π/2 < bata <π/2  domain. so, the answer should correct at this range. so, what should i do for getting correct answer at π/2 < bata < 3π/2 .

Answer (score 0):

Using arctan(beta), I would use this psuedocode:

```
if( beta > (3*π)/2 )
    beta = beta - 2*π
else if( beta > π/2 ) 
    beta = beta - π

answer = arctan(beta)
```

You should be aware that if your angle is exactly 90º or 270º ($\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3\pi}{2}$), then `arctan` is undefined. You should probably catch those cases first.